# Swift 4 change string to URL

Tags: swift, string, url

I'm fairly new to swift, but I've tried everything and can't get this to work.

```
var itemValue: String!
var itemURL: URL!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("itemValue is", itemValue!)
    guard let itemURL = URL(string: itemValue) else {
        return
    }
```

itemURL is not getting a value, even though I have verified that the itemValue string is set correctly (in a previous vc, prepare for segue).

Comment: Can you add here your url string?

Comment: The point is, not every string is a valid URL. So `itemValue` could easily be one of those.

Comment: It's just a URL, something like https://website.com.  It's a valid URL

Comment: I don't care what it is "like". You need to tell us what it _is_.

Comment: Moreover, the string `website.com` is not a valid URL, this is a hostname. A valid URL containing a hostname **must** start with a non-empty scheme component followed by a colon (see the specs). Some browsers allow you to give them a hostname where you should give an URL, but this does not mean that this is a valid URL.

Comment: I've tried many.  Latest one I tried was https://www.wikipedia.org/

Comment: May you give us the swift line used to set this value, and tell when/where it is called, in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `guard let itemURL = URL(string: itemValue)`, you create a new **local constant** named itemURL, that has nothing to do with the **global variable** that has the same name. Moreover, this new local constant has not the same type than the global variable. The global variable is an implicitly unwrapped optional, so this is an optional, but the local constant is not an optional.

This is why you say that *itemURL is not getting a value*: you want the global variable named itemURL to get a value, but you only set a value to the local constant that has the same name. Those two similar identifiers do not store their content in the same memory location.

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation.  I can't believe I missed that.
I removed the global variable, but still am not getting a value in itemURL.

Comment: Add `print("content:", itemURL)` at the end of `viewDidLoad()`, you'll see that you get a value in itemURL. If not, please give the whole code, because with the snippet you wrote in your question, you must get a value in itemURL.

Answer (score 1):

```
let url : String = "url string here"
let urlStr : String = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
let convertedURL : URL = URL(string: urlStr)!
print(convertedURL)
```

try to put your URL string in this code and I hope it will work for you .